# Dynamic property on JavaScript object getting null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set the dynamic property on a javascript object using the ng-model. But I'm unable to create it as I always get null for that property. I have different ways to copy the value from the variable self.username to self.params javascript object in the below code.

Please see this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/rJkATibYppflgthInqbT?p=preview)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="routes.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#/carriers">Carriers</a>

  <div class="mainContainer" ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

routes.js

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/carriers', {
      templateUrl: 'carriers.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'mainCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

Carriers.html

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="username" ng-model="mainCtrl.username" />
<button  ng-click="mainCtrl.login()">Login</button>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var self = this;
  self.username = '';
  self.login = login;
  self.params = {
    username: self.username //doesnt work
  };
  //self.params.username=angular.copy(self.username);    //doesnt work
  //self.params['username']=self.username; //doesnt work
  function login() {
    //   alert(self.username);
    console.dir(self.username); // works
    console.dir(self.params); // username:'' getting empty string for username property
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value does not update because you created a new object and set the value of `self.params.username` to the value of `self.params`. `self.params.username` does not reference `self.params` it was just set from the value when the object was created.

If you want to bind `self.params.username` to the input then you can change your input model to:

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="username" ng-model="mainCtrl.params.username" />
```

Another alternative is to watch `self.username` and set the value of `self.params.username` to the new value using [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

```
// watch mainCtrl.username for any changes
$scope.$watch('mainCtrl.username', function(newValue, oldValue) {

    // set self.params.username from the new value
    self.params.username = newValue;

});
```

Comment: "Works for me" isn't a very useful answer.

Comment: @papakia sorry for terminology I actually meant empty string. I need actual value instead of empty string

Comment: @koushikR No problem! Does my answer help you understand the problem?

Comment: @Juhana Why the down vote? I know it was not right to include the words "Works for me" in my answer but I amended it straight away

Comment: Yes, it did thnx!! @papakia

Comment: No problem at all @koushikR :)

Comment: Is there any way to copy the value from self.username to self.params.username? @papakia

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122779/discussion-between-papakia-and-koushik-r).

Comment: @koushikR See this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SzrwXoQeYFhO6WWMgtGN?p=preview)